# How to trigger update action in Phoenix Controller?

Tags: api, elixir, phoenix-framework

Under the `update` test I use:

```
%{resp_body: body} = conn
|> sign_in
|> patch(asset_path(conn, :update), Poison.encode!(payload))
```

I get this error:

```
 ** (ArgumentError) No action :update for helper Web.Router.Helpers.asset_path/2. The following actions/clauses are supported:

     asset_path(conn_or_endpoint, :create, , opts \\ [])
     asset_path(conn_or_endpoint, :delete, id, opts \\ [])
     asset_path(conn_or_endpoint, :edit, id, opts \\ [])
     asset_path(conn_or_endpoint, :index, , opts \\ [])
     asset_path(conn_or_endpoint, :new, , opts \\ [])
     asset_path(conn_or_endpoint, :show, id, opts \\ [])
     asset_path(conn_or_endpoint, :update, id, opts \\ [])
 code: |> post(asset_path(conn, :update), Poison.encode!(payload))
 stacktrace:
   (phoenix) lib/phoenix/router/helpers.ex:299: Phoenix.Router.Helpers.raise_route_error/5
   test/controllers/asset_controller_test.exs:167: (test)
```

When I use Postman to test it directly it works fine though.

I have used `post(asset_path(conn, :create), Poison.encode!(payload))` in the `insert` action and it works fine.

Here is the snapshot of postman to show that code works fine, test fails.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `update` route and therefore `asset_path` for `update` action requires the id of the resource. You need to pass that as the third argument of `asset_path`, e.g.

```
|> patch(asset_path(conn, :update, id), Poison.encode!(payload))
```

`id` should be the `id` of the record you're trying to update

Answer (score 0):

You can check by typing *mix phx.routes*. The update action always require id to work. so pass the id and it should work